# count cumulative values across factor levels over time in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, cumsum

I have a very large dataframe that looks like so:

```
month <- c(201101, 201101, 201101, 201102, 201102, 201102, 201103, 201103, 201103, 201104, 201104, 201104)
su <- as.factor(c(045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238,045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238))
item <- as.factor(c(045110B238A01, 045110B238A02, 045110B238A03, 045110B238A01, 045110B238A02, 045110B238A03, 045110B238A01, 045110B238A02, 045110B238A03, 045110B238A01, 045110B238A02, 045110B238A03))
item.dlq <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(month, su, item, item.dlq)
```

Using the item.dlq variable I count the cumulative number of months for which each itemcode has item.dlq == 1:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(df %>%
        group_by(itemcode, grp = cumsum(item.dlq == 0)) %>%
        mutate(item.cum.dlq = cumsum(item.dlq)))
```

which should give me a vector like so:

```
item.cum.dlq <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4)
```

Based on the information above, I would like to

1. create a variable that counts the number of consecutive months in which ALL items for the su have values of dlq==1.
2. count the number of consecutive months when at least 1 itemcode has a value of 1.  For example, where month is equal to 201102 (i.e. 2/2011), item 045110B238A02 has item.dlq == 0, so only 2/3 items have dlq == 1.

Note that there is only one value of su in the example above, but there are many in the full data frame I am working with.  I would also like to compress the data frame as well, if possible, to avoid carrying around unnecesary observations.  Here is what the raw data would look like without compressing:

```
su.cum.fulldlq <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2) ## all items dlq ==1
su.cum.partdlq <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ## at least 1 item but not all have dlq == 1
```

If the data frame were compressed, it would look like so:

```
month <- c(201101, 201102, 201103, 201104)
su <- c(045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238, 045110B238)
su.cum.fulldlq <- c(1, 0, 1, 2)
su.cum.partdlq <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this, but I keep getting error messages.

```
df <- data.frame(df %>%
   group_by(su, month)) %>%
   mutate(burden = n_distinct(itemcode)) # count number of items
   mutate(dlq.items = n_distinct(dlq == 1)) %>% # count number of items where dlq == 1
   mutate(full.dlq = ifelse(burden == dlq_items, 1, 0)) %>% # if number of items equals the number of items with dlq == 1, then full.dlq == 1.
```

after this i am not certain at all.

Is there a way to do so using dplyr?  If not, any other approaches would be welcome.  If something is not clear please comment and I will change it. Either way, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Comment: There are a lot of duplicated records in the data frame you give, literally 7 out of 12 rows are duplicated from other rows. How do you differentiate them? By row number?

Comment: @Psidom I would like to differentiate by the month variable.  In this example, the su is the same for all records because the item comes from the su (hence A01, A02, A03 after the value for su).  If it is still unclear I will come up with a more varied example.

Comment: I think in your example, all the records are `A01`, is that intentional or mistake?

Comment: @Psidom thanks just made edits.  It was a mistake.